# How to draw progress bar like npm in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, npm, terminal

The progress bar is like this image

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Andrew,the answer used "#",but i want to draw it like this image

Comment: look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this example](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/07/16/a-progress-bar-for-the-shell/).

[image]

Code is included there

Comment: Web Site is not opening.