# How to use tqdm in bash for loops?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, progress-bar, tqdm

I have this `for loop` for example that takes so much time to finish so I want to use `tqdm` to have a nice progress bar like in python. But I can't find any way to do it?

```
for f in `find mydir -name *.jpg -print`; do cp $f images/${f//\//_}; done
```

How can I get a progress bar for this loop?

Comment: better yet, search here for `[linux] find xargs parallel` . Assuming you have multiple cores and extra memory, you can process multiple files atht same time. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a really old question, but currently [the readme for `tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) says that using it as a command in bash works fine, e.g.:

```sh
$ seq 9999999 | tqdm --bytes | wc -l
75.2MB [00:00, 217MB/s]
9999999

$ tar -zcf - docs/ | tqdm --bytes --total `du -sb docs/ | cut -f1` \
    > backup.tgz
 32%|██████████▍                      | 8.89G/27.9G [00:42<01:31, 223MB/s]
```

However, `tqdm` showing a progress bar is dependent on the command giving it information to build a progress bar from, which `cp` doesn't (even `cp -v` doesn't send buffered info, so you'll only get the progress bar once `cp` completes).

That said, if you want a progress bar for copying files you should like into either [`rsync --progress`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+--progress+**%2F*.jpg+target) or the [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) command.

Using `rsync`, the command to solve your question could be something like:

```sh
rsync -avzh --progress **/*.jpg images/
```

Answer (score 7):

To use `tqdm` in a Bash loop, you need:

1. to output something
2. to know the total number of iterations (optional)
3. to add tqdm after the `done`.

In your case:

```sh
total=1000
for f in `find mydir -name *.jpg -print`; do echo $f; cp $f images/${f//\//_}; done | tqdm --total $total >> /dev/null
```

See the answer: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/436#issuecomment-330504048

Answer (score -7):

tqdm is dedicated for python, not for bash..
Instead, if you just want to display the progress of your loop, you may just need a "symbolic" progress bar, like the answer by @Mitch Haile to the question [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script)

You may need to calculate the progress by (executed loops number)/(total loops number) according to your need.
E.g.

```
Loop_array=(`find mydir -name *.jpg -print`);
Total_loop_num=${#Loop_array[*]};
for((i=0;i<$Total_loop_num;i++))
do
   echo -ne "Progress: $[ ($i+1)*100/$Total_loop_num ]%\r";
   f=${Loop_array[$i]};
   cp $f images/${f//\//_};
done;
echo "Loop finished.";
```

It should work as long as your original commands work. I've just tested on the following code and it works fine:

```
for((i=0;i<120000;i++))
do
   echo -ne "Progress: $[ ($i+1)*100/120000 ]%\r";
done;
```

If you also want a "real" progress bar like the series of "#", you can calculate for every N loops to add a "#" to a string then echo it.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Thanks. I actually don't know about tqdm and I don't have it installed either. I just google and found it a module of python.

Comment: You, sir, didn't read the manual which gives a nice introduction on using tqdm in the terminal ;)