# Implement progress bar

Tags: bash, shell, unix, progress-bar

I found this great progress bar: [Great Example](https://gist.github.com/caballerojavier13/3ea551a132b7523bac0ea5d2b6c778ac)

How can I implement this progress bar when curl running and do sort and unique etc on really big file (60GB) taking about ~ 3 hours.

Example: `count="$(awk '{print $1}' $FILE_NAME | sort -T /diskXX --parallel=$PARALLEL | uniq | wc -l)"`

Thanks! 
Guy

Answer (score 1):

With `pv`:

```
pv "$FILE_NAME" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -T /diskXX --parallel="$PARALLEL" | uniq | wc -l
```

or from stdin with size in gigabyte:

```
pv -s 60g <"$FILE_NAME" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -T /diskXX --parallel="$PARALLEL" | uniq | wc -l
```

From `man pv`:

> pv  shows  the  progress  of  data through a pipeline by giving information such as time elapsed, percentage completed (with progress bar), current
>          throughput rate, total data transferred, and ETA

Comment: How can I run `pv` and save to variable:  `count=pv "$FILE_NAME" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -T /diskXX --parallel="$PARALLEL" | uniq | wc -l`?
Thank YOU! Great :)

Comment: Usually like this: `count=$(pv "$FILE_NAME" | awk '{print $1}' | sort -T /diskXX --parallel="$PARALLEL" | uniq | wc -l)`

Comment: Unfortunately `pv` should be installed separately.
So I go back to thinking about how to implement the first option in code

Comment: Here is a [pure bash progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298090/1765658)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to implement your own progress visualization function, by printing a status (or progress bar) in the same line (i.e. overwriting the previous content of the line).

For example you can use "echo -n" in a loop to always print the assumed runtime percentage of a background process (10%, 20%, 30%).

Edit:
You might find this [question and collection of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-tot-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-scrip) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I don't use a look, I need to run a script in one line that will be a process. I do not know how to add this to a progress  bar :)