# Add a header in a Bash script, over the output of commands

Tags: bash, centos7

I made a bash script which runs some commands (will install some applications and configure others). I want to show the output of the commands because if I'll hide them, the user will think there was an error or something else (as some command will take a lot of time to finnish). But I need to show a "header" like area, permamently in the top of the program (over the output of the commands), with the steps of the installation. I don't know how can this be done in a bash script but I think it is possible as I saw this:

[image: Look at the green "Progress"]

Where the green "Progress" is all the time over the output of the command.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script possible duplicate

Comment: Can you use `screen` or `tmux`? You could set a header in those programs. If not - I think you would have to write a C program that handles that, using some ncurses, duplicating what `screen` already does. Or you can struggle a lot in bash using ansi escape sequences and some output post-processing, manually shifting screen up and moving cursor around.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, I will try `screen` and `tmux`! Thank you very much! I didn't know about these.