# Progress bar while Unix find command is executing

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csh

I have a simple Unix  shell script which is executing a time-consuming `find` command. Till it executes, my script appears non-responsive. However it's actually running in reality.
How can I add a progress bar or print dots till the `find` command is executing?

I want to print some dots or hash till the function `doSomething` is executing.

```
function doSomething()
{
  # Time-consuming 'for' loop below
  for var in `find XXXXXX`
  do
      # Some more processing
  done;
}

# Call the function doSomething. Need the progress DOTS till doSomething is executing
doSomething

# Remaining script processing
```

I have tried to google, but none of the solutions fits what I am trying to achieve. Any suggestions?

Comment: The concept of `find` is that it searches through an unknown amount of files. Progress implies that you know how many searches it will take. What you are after is more an activity indicator.

Comment: Also it is very unclear what you really want. You could just write in your do-loop `echo -n .` and you will get a single dot every time a file is processed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073

Comment: Even more related: https://serverfault.com/questions/341143/

Comment: Hmm... certainly for find it is difficult to know how it is progressing, since you don't know how many files it will find. But you could do some sort of pulse bar or "spinny". Probably you could do this as a tool on the output pipe that emits to stderr: `find what-ever | spinny --expect_lines 50 | xargs archive`. If there is a `--expect` argument then it counts the amount of piped input.to generate a progress bar, otherwise it just does a pulsing `. .. ...` or zylon bar or similar. In either case it pipes the content through to the next pipe stage.

Comment: As already commented out, given unknown size of work, impossible to create a pipeline with % competed. As an alternative, consider using 'pv', which will show progress bar.

Comment: Can you provide some information about the 'find' command ? Is 'some more processing' time consuming ? you might want to pipe the `find` into the processing, potentially, using xargs -P to process files in parallel, if relevant.

Comment: aside: `for var in $(find ...)` is inherently buggy. `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do ...; done < <(find ... -print0)` is the alternative robust against surprising or malicious filenames; see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions)

Answer (score 1):

You can run a spinner in the background

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

spinner() {
  local s="|/-\\"
  local -i i=0
  while :; do
    printf "%s\\r" "${s:i++%4:1}" >&2
    sleep .05
  done
}

function doSomething()
{
  # time consuming for loop below
  while read -r -d '' var
  do
    : #some more processing
  done < <(find XXXXXX -print0)
}

# Start the spinner in the background
spinner &

# Get the spinner PID
spinner_pid=$!
#call the function doSomething. Need the progress DOTS till doSomething is executing
doSomething

# Terminate the background running spinner
kill $spinner_pid

# remaining script processing
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, how about a simple spinner? It is easy enough to knock something up in `awk`, which copies input to standard output and prints a spinner to standard error:

```
$ cat spinner.awk
{ printf "%s\r", substr("|/-\\", NR % 4 + 1, 1) > "/dev/stderr" }

1
```

which you can then pipe `find` through.

```
  for var in `find XXXXXX | awk -f spinner.awk`
  do
      #some more processing
  done;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the OP how many files are selected by the find command, and if the do-something has any significant impact on the overall processing time.

Assuming one of the common cases, where (1) `find` will scan large number of folders (2) relatively small number of matches and (3) little processing for each file, it is possible to create progress indication by logging directory that are scanned.

If the original find was using `find STARTING-POINT ... FIND-EXPRESSION`, the modified command is `find STARTING-POINT '(' LOGGING-EXPRESSION ')' -o '( FIND-EXPRESSION ')'`.

Following script will produce a progress report whenever find start scanning a new folder. Note that FIND-EXPRESSION should include explicit '-print', if the original find was relying on the implicit -print.

```
find STARTING-POINT   \
     '(' -type d -maxdepth 3 -fprintf /dev/stderr "Processing: %p" ')'   \
     -o \
     '(' FIND-EXPRESSION ')'

# Single Line
find STARTING-POINT '(' -type d -maxdepth N -fprintf /dev/stderr "Processing\n: %p" ')' -oo '(' FIND-EXPRESSION ')'
```

The above will log each scanned folder (up to N level deep) to stderr.

Example:

```
# Find all '*.py' files on the system, showing '*' for each folder
find / '(' -type d -fprintf /dev/stderr "*" ')' -o '(' -name '*.py' -print ')'

# Find system '*.so' files, showing each folder scanned
find /lib /usr/lib '(' -type d  -fprintf /dev/stderr "Scanning: %p" ')' -o '(' -name '*.so' -print ')'
```

Additional customization to the logging can be performed - Using the '-regex' or '-path' in the logging filter