# Reading a training progress log file, but binaries are written in it

Tags: python, bash, logging

I was running a program, and it will output the progress bar to a file `train.2.log`. Here's a link to the file [train.2.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8prxn9i364riab6/train.2.log), which looks like the following on terminal :

This is line 1

```
Training ...
```

This is line 2

```
epoch       iteration   main/loss   main/loss_ctc  main/loss_att ...
```

This is line 3

```
0           100         455.209     899.082        264.978 ...
```

There are no problems when u were to call `head -n3 train.2.log`, it shows the first 3 lines very well, but in the text file its not human-readable, because of the binaries `<0x1b>` that are written within it (see [train.2.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8prxn9i364riab6/train.2.log)).

**Question** : How do i modify the file such that it becomes human readable ?

Usually progress bars are written such that `\r` is used instead of `\n`, following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script?rq=1).
Hence i tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60786499/removing-progress-bar-from-program-output-redirected-into-log-file/60786606?noredirect=1#comment107862942_60786606), which did not work as the [program that i called](https://github.com/espnet/espnet/blob/master/egs/librispeech/asr1/run.sh/#L217-L235) doesn't seem to be using `\r`.

Comment: can you turn off the progress feature of the program creating train.2.log? OTherwise, we'll need to see a small set of sample log file, the required output from that same sample, any code, current output or error messages you have. Please add this information to the body of your question using the `{}` tool from the edit menu on mouse-selected text to have correctly formatted `data/output/code/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Try the "strings" command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you output both training progress & it's log to the same output stream. If you got the `train.2.log` by redirecting the Python output to a file in terminal (`app.py > train.log`), but still want to observe it's progress, then I'd suggest printing the log to a separate stream, like `stderr`.

You can achieve that in Python with `print("Log message", file=sys.stderr)`, then redirect program output:

```sh
app.py 2>train.log
```

This way `app.py` will print the progress bar to `stdout` as usual, while the training log is available on `stderr` without progress indication mixed in.