# Progress-bar for the long GateKeeper app validation

Tags: validation, progress-bar

I have several scientific applications weighting 400Mb or more.
The first launch is very long (up to 60" on some Macs) presumably due to the validation of the many binaries which are inside the bundle.
Some users are not patient enough and trash everything before the validation process can complete.
Is there a way to add a progression bar which will report on the actual validation work of GateKeeper ?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What about this suggestion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link. I already used progression bars in shell scripts but then I knew the number of files to be proceeded or I had an estimate of the duration time. In the case of GateKeeper my question is about a way to tack the progression of the app validation process to produce a realistic progression bar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered echoing dots until your app is accepted, which can be known using `spctl -av /path/to/app`?

Comment: Yes, I am working at this solution which is not exactly what I wanted but is a reasonable workaround.