# Progress indicator in bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell, progress-bar

How can I add progress percentage in the for loop of bash script. Below is one example of the script in which for loop takes a lot of time due to huge data. I would like to know the complete percentage of the for loop.

```
for domain in $(cat all-programs.txt); do
   cat 2020.json.gz | pigz -dc | grep ".$domain" | cut -d "," -f2 | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d '"' -f2 | sed '/^$domain/d' | sort -u | grep -w "$domain" 2>/dev/null >> all.txt; done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: Off-topic: You can add a newline after each `|` (and indent), avoiding long lines. The `done` can be placed on a new line as well,

Comment: Off-topic: The dot in your grep command is matching any character. Demo: `printf "%s\n" "sample.txt" "wrong.xtxt" | grep ".txt"`. You might want to replace it with `[.]`. Demo: `printf "%s\n" "sample.txt" "wrong.xtxt" | grep "[.]txt"`

Comment: Off topic: Before putting too much effort in the progress bar, look for how to improve the performance of the loop. Different `cuts` can be joined together. More inportant: for a large number of `domains` you will also be calling `pigz` very often. Post a new question with sample input (at least 4 domains) and output, asking how to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The example you post actually have an issue of performance, since each loop will unzip the same file repeatedly, maybe you should first change the structure of the loop? The answer maybe very different if the structure changed.

However, for the general case of the problem, the `showing percentage part`, I recommend using awk.

**Option 1: Show `for Loop` percentage**

Calculate percentage for the `for loop`'s `current iteration / total iterations`.

```sh
ALL=$(cat all-programs.txt)
LEN=${#ALL[@]}
for ((i = 0; i < $LEN; ++i)); do
    awk -v total=$LEN -v cur=$i '
    function bar(x){s="";i=0; while (i++ < x) s=s "#";return s}
    BEGIN{
        percent=int(cur / total * 100);
        printf "%s %s%%\r", bar(percent*.8), percent
    }
    END { print }
    '
done
```

**Option 2: Show `per file` percentage**

Calculate percentage for per file `current length / total size`, for the case showing percentage of `ver_big_file.json` progress.

```sh
for domain in $(cat all-programs.txt); do
    awk '
    function bar(x){s="";i=0;while (i++ < x) s=s "#";return s}
    BEGIN{
        ("ls -l " ARGV[1]) | getline total;
        split(total,array);
        total=array[5];
    }
    {
        cur+=length($0)+1;
        percent=int(cur / total * 100);
        printf "LINE %s:%s %s%%\r", NR, bar(percent*.8), percent 
    }
    END {print}' very_big_file.json | grep ".$domain" | ...
done
```

You can combine **Option 1** and **Option 2** together as you need.