# SED: Is there a simpler way to measure percentage complete

Tags: bash, sed

So, I am processing a lot of data and outputting to a file. Sed doesn't give me any progress directly, however, I know that for every line of input there must be a line of output. With that in mind, I have devised a way to track progress indirectly with sed (here's a simple example):

```
printf 'line: %d\n' {1..1000} | sed -un -e '0~10p' | sed -un = | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 printf '%d%%\r'
```

This works, but I wonder if it could be simpler.

Here is the more complicated (actual production) problem:

```
    local one_percent
    one_percent=$(bc -l <<< "$(wc -l "${original}"| cut -d' ' -f1) / 100")

    sed  -E -n -f "${remapper}"  "${original}" | tee "${mapping_file}" | sed -un "0~${one_percent%%.*}p"  | sed -un = | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 printf '%02d%%\r' > /dev/stderr
```

Can this be improved?

**update** Unfortunately, `pv` isn't available on the final vm and I don't have privs to add it.

Comment: Maybe with [`pv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html)?

Comment: [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238073/4154375) might be useful.

Comment: _ for every line of input there must be a line of output_ : If you intend to run one or more child processes for each input line, better ensure that you don't have more than a few dozens input line; otherwise you will need a lot of patience to wait until your script finishes.

Answer (score 4):

If your `sed` is GNU `sed` you can add this progression to your `sed` script, something like:

```
sed -e '0~100w /dev/stderr' -f "${remapper}" ...
```

Every 100 lines, starting from line 100, we write the current line to `/dev/stderr`. You can then post-process `/dev/stderr` with, e.g., `awk` to count the lines and produce a progress bar.

Here is an easy to test dummy example, with a 1M lines input generated by `seq`. The main `sed` script just replaces all characters with a `x` (`s/./x/g`) and the standard output is discarded to `/dev/null`; replace with your actual main processing and redirection. The `awk` script prints `cr` (`0x0d`), the input line number (`NR`) on 3 digits (`%03d`), and a `%`. Its standard output is redirected to the standard error. If the shown progression is too fast to see try with `n` = 10M.

```
echo 's/./x/g' > remapper
n=1000000
((m=n/100))
seq 1 "$n" |
  sed -e '0~'"$m"'w /dev/stderr' -f remapper > /dev/null 2> \
  >( awk '{printf("\x0d%03d%%", NR)} END {print ""}' 1>&2 )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy reading the input multiple times, as you seem to be, then with `pv`:

```
sed -E -n -f "$remapper" "$original" |
pv -l -s $(wc -l "$original" | awk NF=1) > "$mapping_file"
```

To avoid re-reading, you can reorder:

```
pv "$original" |
sed -E -n -f "$remapper" > "$mapping_file"
```

Comment: I started to go down this route until I determined that `pv` isn't available on the system I am running on :(

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno then you could perhaps update your question to make that point clear to every potential helpers?  And also you could add information about your OS.

Answer (score 1):

I also think, it's better to use the `pv` (pipe viewer), because `pv -l -s 1000` is used to indicate that the input consists of lines (`-l`) and the total number of lines is 1000 (`-s 1000`), so the `pv` will then display the progress as a percentage!

something like this

```
printf 'line: %d\n' {1..1000} | sed -un -e '0~10p' | pv -l -s 1000 | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 printf '%d%%\r' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's a suggestion using `tail` and `awk`.

```
#! /bin/sh

set -o errexit -o nounset

InputFile='./src'
OutputFile='./output'
SED_Script='./cmd.sed'

Total="$(wc -l "$InputFile")"
Total="${Total%% *}"

sed -f "$SED_Script" "$InputFile" >"$OutputFile" &

tail --pid="$!" -f "$OutputFile" \
  | awk -v Mod="$((Total / 100))" -- 'BEGIN { FS = "\n"; Count = 0;  }
                                       !(NR % Mod) { printf "%3u%%\r", ++ Count; fflush() }'

echo 'Done!'
```

The idea is to leave SED work in the background, building its output file as fast as possible, unimpeded by any additional pipelines.

Progress monitoring is achieved with `awk` taking its input from `tail` (which will terminate when the SED background process has ended).

Tested with a 980,000 line long input file, with `mawk` and `gawk` under Debian 11.

---

##### Update

Ditched `pv` in favour of `awk` since the former isn't available in OP's environment.

Answer (score 1):

I decided not to add `sed` commands because I don't know what you might be doing in your `$remapper`, and didn't want to alter your possible logging.

`awk` handles record counts, math and output control better than `sed`, so I used that for a simple single-process wrapper.

```
$: awk 'NR==FNR{onepct=NR/100} # define how many records is one percent
        NR>FNR && 0==FNR%onepct { printf "\r%02d%%", ++pctcnt } 
        END{printf "\n"}       # add a clean newline at the end
       ' "$original" <( sed -un -f "$remapper" "$original" )
```

It could certainly be improved, but the `awk` silently scans though your original file once to get the number of lines and assign what one percent of those would be. It then reads through the output of your `sed` command as-is, and uses modulo division to only print once on each percent-without-remainder line. I used a simple increment for percentage output.

Keeping the operations in memory and generating fewer processes and less overall IO should speed things up if it's a sizeable dataset.

A simple pipe works just as well, just use a dash as the second input:

```
$: sed -un -f "$remapper" "$original" |
   awk 'NR==FNR{onepct=FNR/100} # define how many records is one percent
        NR>FNR && 0==NR%onepct { printf "\r%02d%%", ++pctcnt } 
        END{printf "\n"}       # add a clean newline at the end
       ' "$original" -
```

If you prefer to handle the record counting with `wc`, it's even simpler.

```
awk -v pct=$(($(wc -l<"$original")/100)) '0==NR%pct{printf "\r%02d%%",++pctcnt} END{printf "\n"}' <(sed -unf "$remapper" "$original")
```

or

```
sed -unf "$remapper" "$original" |
 awk -v pct=$(($(wc -l<"$original")/100)) '0==NR%pct{printf "\r%02d%%",++pctcnt} END{printf "\n"}'
```

Of course, to preserve your output you either need the `tee` or could have `awk` do it.

```
sed -unf "$remapper" "$original" | tee "${mapping_file}" |
 awk -v pct=$(($(wc -l<"$original")/100)) '0==NR%pct{printf "\r%02d%%",++pctcnt} END{printf "\n"}'
```

or

```
sed -unf "$remapper" "$original" | 
 awk -v pct=$(($(wc -l<"$original")/100)) -v out="$mapping_file" '
   { print > out }
   0==NR%pct { printf "\r%02d%%", ++pctcnt }
   END { printf "\n"; close(out); } '
```

Comment: Be aware that you are getting integer math for the percentage, and there may be a few records processed at the end after the `100%` prints but before it finishes. Likewise, saying `%02d`will force *at least* two digits, but the final `100%` message exceeds the spec and is all printed. That's unlikely to be an issue, but better to be aware of such details.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that already and made some adjustments. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `pv` is apparently unavailable, here's an approach
using the `status=progress` feature of GNU `dd`, which might be more available, and any `awk`.

It can be dropped into a command to replace the (single) input filename. Probably can't be used sensibly with piped input since total size can't be calculated.

Define a bash function (could also be a bash shell script):

```
show_progress()(
    # $1 is a file to read

    # add error checking here

    # stat can be approximated by "du -sk" scaled appropriately
    sz=$(stat -c%s "$1")

    dd status=progress if="$1" 2> >(
        awk -v sz=$sz -v RS=$'\r' '
            BEGIN { pc = 100/sz }
            $2=="bytes" {
                printf "%.2f%%\r", $1*pc
                fflush()
            }
        ' 1>&2
    ) &&
    echo "100.00%" 1>&2
)
```

Use in a bash commandline as:

```
sed -E -n -f "$remapper" <(show_progress "$original") >"$mapping_file"
```

or (implemented as a bash script) with any POSIX shell:

```
show_progress "$original" |
sed -E -n -f "$remapper" >"$mapping_file"
```

The `>(...)` is bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). `2> >(...)` redirects stderr to the named pipe (the space is important).

The nice thing is that the input file does not have to be scanned multiple times, nor the output scanned.

Note that there is a potential lag after final progress message is printed (after input is consumed), if processing is slow.

Comment: I'm wrong. Using `dd` is obviously an extra pass over the input.

Comment: To have just a single pass over the input, on linux one could loop reading `pos` from /proc/`pid`/fdinfo/* in a separate process. But for that, installing [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) probably becomes simpler to maintain, and much more powerful.